# I am integrating web SDK of clever Tap for analytics but getting clevertap.getCleverTapID() null in console. also events not tracked in dashboard

Tags: javascript, analytics, clevertap

I am integrating events analytics in clever tap for one website. i followed all steps as mentioned in this link. https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/web-quickstart-guide#section-next-steps but events are not getting tracked in clever Tap Dashboard. while i was debugging it in cosnsole i got to know that i am getting null value of clevertap.getCleverTapID(). Please help me in this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @shashi_coder Can you please let us know how you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

provide region in clevertap object eg: in1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).